# Why Chrome dev tools mangles base64 image values?

Tags: google-chrome, base64, google-chrome-devtools

I'd like to know why base64 images are mangled in Chrome's dev tools Watch values: 
When I right click on the underlined value -> "copy value" Chrome decides to remove a GREAT part of the original base64 code, and to add "..." in between, destroying the base64 encoding

[image]

After making a text diff between what I've obtained from Chrome dev tools and the base64 data that reaches the server and I found there was a huge part of the text missing on what Chrome shows as the value and the infamous "..." (indicating that there should be more code in between i guess) that should't be there either

So What should I do to be able to retreive the proper value of a base64 image on Chrome dev tools?

Comment: This is a bug. You can report it on https://crbug.com and you can use `copy(your.variable)` in console.

Comment: I can't reproduce it in 60.0.3112.113. "copy value" works as expected, I'm getting a valid base64'd image.